# Reading tilt sensor from live wallpaper

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am in the process of making my first live wallpaper. I am starting out from the code in the sample [CubeWallpaper](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/index.html) and modifying it. So far things have been going fine, I am now drawing my own, completely different, animated graphics.

I now wish for my graphics to respond to the degree of tilt of the phone. I have implemented a tilt sensor before in a non-wallpaper app. But when I attempt to include my tilting code into the wallpaper, the `onSensorChanged()` method does not appear to ever get called - at least my Log message never appears in logcat.

One thing I'm not sure about is where to append the `implements SensorEventListener`. Should it be to my class that extends `WallpaperService` or its child class that extends `Engine`?.. Actually I've tried it both ways - and neither appeared to work. Is there something extra that may need to be done to get the tilt working?

**EDIT:** Currently I am guessing that the `implements SensorEventListener` is appended to class that extends `Engine`, so the gist of my code is as follows:

**EDIT:** Could it be something to do with which thread the SensorEventListener is running on? I read somewhere that it needs to be on the UI thread.

```
public class MicksWallPaper extends WallpaperService 
{
    // blah blah

    class MyWallPaper extends Engine implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener , SensorEventListener 
    {
        SensorManager sensorManager = null;
        onCreate()
        {
            sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
        {
        Log.i("wp:","onSensorChanged"); // I never see this message
            synchronized (this) 
            {
                switch (event.sensor.getType())
                {
                    case Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION:
                        pitch = event.values[1];
                        Log.i("pitch=",""+pitch);
                    break;
                }
            }       
        }
    }    
}
```

**EDIT:** Problem solved. How embarrassing - I'd simply forgotten to call registerListener for my sensorManager.

Comment: Add your final edit as an answer to your own question...you can get more SO brownie points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(On Ogre's advice...)

Problem solved. How embarrassing - I'd simply forgotten to call registerListener for my sensorManager.